# carousel-indicators don't work in IE

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have problems getting carousel-indicators to work in any version of IE. I can't click them. Here is my html code:

```
<div id="presentation" class="tab-pane active">      
    <div id="presentationCarousel" class="carousel slide">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#presentationCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#presentationCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#presentationCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active"><img src="...1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="item "><img src="...2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
            <div class="item "><img src="...3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
   interval: 4000  
})
```

Comment: Why are your carousel indicators outside of the carousel div? I'm not sure if it matters. And why do all of your items have the `active` class?

Comment: i write it like a sample from boostram site, and i edit about `active`

Comment: What are the image urls? `src="...2.jpg"` I don't think that'll work

Comment: And what exactly do you want to click? They're not supposed to be clickable? Do you want a "Previous" and "Next" button?

Comment: This works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/N3ZEC/ . I put the "carousel-indicators" **in** the carousel, and used real URLs for the images. It works fine. What do you want to click?

Comment: Corrected, but still at least in the example works in ie but not in practice. Here is the [link](http://www.cae-fidesys.com/ru) to the site. Unfortunately the site has no English version yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this from a `file:///` URL? In that case you need to make IE trust the page enough to run scripts. There's probably a warning at the bottom: "IE restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls" showing for a few seconds on load. Click allow and everything should work or load it from a web server so you get `http://`.